# switch mysql database while loading dump

Tags: mysql, tableau-api, database-administration

We have a reporting server which loads dump every four hours and the load takes probably 15 mins. My idea is to create a duplicate and make tableau to switch to the duplicate when the load runs on the primary database. But I am not sure how to make this work from the tableau side or from the mysql? Any ideas?

Comment: Use a Master / Slave Replication. So your reporting-Server can use the Slave DB Server

Comment: @BerndBuffen  We just have one server that we could use for now. We will have to do it in the same server

Comment: the simplest way is to configure a second server on the same server. You only need a separate my.cnf where you can use a other port and data_dir